# Wormhole Recursion with Bessie the cow

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

This is the description on the USACO website:

Farmer John's hobby of conducting high-energy physics experiments on weekends has backfired, causing N wormholes (2 <= N <= 12, N even) to materialize on his farm, each located at a distinct point on the 2D map of his farm (the x,y coordinates are both integers).

According to his calculations, Farmer John knows that his wormholes will form N/2 connected pairs. For example, if wormholes A and B are connected as a pair, then any object entering wormhole A will exit wormhole B moving in the same direction, and any object entering wormhole B will similarly exit from wormhole A moving in the same direction. This can have rather unpleasant consequences.

For example, suppose there are two paired wormholes A at (1,1) and B at (3,1), and that Bessie the cow starts from position (2,1) moving in the +x direction. Bessie will enter wormhole B [at (3,1)], exit from A [at (1,1)], then enter B again, and so on, getting trapped in an infinite cycle!

Farmer John knows the exact location of each wormhole on his farm. He knows that Bessie the cow always walks in the +x direction, although he does not remember where Bessie is currently located.

Please help Farmer John count the number of distinct pairings of the wormholes such that Bessie could possibly get trapped in an infinite cycle if she starts from an unlucky position. FJ doesn't know which wormhole pairs with any other wormhole, so find all the possibilities.

So far I have everything except how to find every possible pairing of wormhole coordinates. I want to put them all in an arraylist of arraylist of pairs, but I don't know how the recursion works.

This is my code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    public class codetester {
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
    {
        wormhole test = new wormhole();

        BufferedReader f= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("wormhole.in"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("wormhole.out")));

        int N=Integer.parseInt(f.readLine());

        ArrayList<Point> rawdata = new ArrayList<Point>();

        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            String [] twocoords=f.readLine().split(" ");
            int x=Integer.parseInt(twocoords[0]);
            int y=Integer.parseInt(twocoords[1]);
            rawdata.add(new Point(x,y));
        }

    }
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Pair<Point,Point>>> possiblepairs(ArrayList<Point> raw)
    {
        ArrayList<Pair<Point,Point>> a= new ArrayList<Pair<Point,Point>>();
        iterate(raw,a,0,1);
        return a;
    }
    public void iterate(ArrayList<Point> raw, ArrayList<Pair<Point,Point>> a, int firstpoint, int secondpoint)
    {
        int count=0;
        if(secondpoint<=raw.size()-1) {
        a.add(new Pair(raw.get(firstpoint),raw.get(secondpoint)));
        iterate(raw,a,firstpoint,secondpoint+1);   
        }

        else {
            count++;
            iterate(raw,a,firstpoint+count,firstpoint+count+1);
        }


    }
    public boolean wormholeinrow(Point currentcoords, ArrayList<Point> raw)
    {
        boolean inrow=false;
        int y=currentcoords.y;
        int x=currentcoords.x;
        for(Point a: raw)
        {
            if(a.getY()==y && a.getX()>x)
            {
                inrow=true;   //made need to return these coords instead. will allow us to transport bessie to next wormhole or decide if she is done. 
            }
        }
        return inrow;
        //if raw y coords contains y. then there is still stuff in the same row. but check if the x coord is greater to see if the point is to the right of the currentcoords.
    }
    public static class Pair<K, V> {

        private final K element0;
        private final V element1;

        public static <K, V> Pair<K, V> createPair(K element0, V element1) {
            return new Pair<K, V>(element0, element1);
        }

        public Pair(K element0, V element1) {
            this.element0 = element0;
            this.element1 = element1;
        }

        public K getElement0() {
            return element0;
        }

        public V getElement1() {
            return element1;
        }

    }
}
```

I've found all possible pairings but I haven't been able to find a way to sort them so that I only get (wormhole 1, wormhole 2), (wormhole 3, wormhole 4), (wormhole 5, wormhole 6). 
So far I have (wormhole 1, wormhole 2), (wormhole 1, wormhole 3), (wormhole 1, wormhole 4)...
The main problem I have is with the iterate method and the possible pairs method.
How do I write and approach the recursion so that I can find all possible pairings so that the pairs are sorted in such a way?

Comment: first you say you dont know how to find every possible pairing of wormhole coordinates then you say you found all possible pairings. So I suggest you take one thing at a time and say exactly what you want - one question

Comment: what i mean is that I found all pairings overall. But my problem is I can't find all sets of pairings. Sets of pairings would be like: wormhole 1 is paired with wormhole 2, then wormhole 3 is paired with wormhole 4 etc.                         All possible pairings just means I have an arraylist of pairs with wormhole 1, wormhole 2. Then wormhole 1 and wormhole 3...wormhole 5, wormhole 6 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand this recursion maybe someone else will go through it

I can set up the problem and what it wants to achieve:

to have the cow fall into the infinite loop she has to be below hole B and hole A below hole B

since the cow moves only the horizontal direction (x) the two holes have to be on the horizontal line that is y1=y2

so if points are A(x1, y1) and B(x2, y2) and the cow is at C(x, y) the condition for infinite loop is

y==y1==y2,

x1 less than x2

and

x1 < x<=x2

If you have the N/2 pairs you can apply this condition to find which pairs the cow may fall in. Start writing the iterative method.